# Can I integrate WebRTC-Native Android demo with my kamilio/freeswitch?

Tags: android, webrtc, voip, freeswitch, apprtcdemo

I m new to here so maybe my question is also looks silly.
If so, please teach me then I will very appreciate for it.

question:

I m going to build webrtc android client for my kamilio/freeswitch.
So I've built webrtc for android and tested AppRTC demo and made video call.
What I want to know is can I integrate this demo with my own kamilio/freeswitch?

Hope to hearing from you soon.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. From the server point of view, WebRTC is WebRTC regardless if you are running it from app or from browser. Just make that your client is using SIP (clear SIP or SIP over websocket as described in [RFC 7118](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7118) since this is the most popular signaling protocol supported also by Kamailio/FreeSWITCH.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely yes. Take a look at FreeSWITCH VerTo protocol which is specifically designed for WebRTC : https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_verto.

Also you can check out this demo on google play, where this protocol implemented with native Android WebRTC SDK:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xyz.vertoandroid.vertoandroidlibdemo. (ahem, shameless plug, sorry).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.